# If $|a-b |<| b |/ 2$, show $| a|> | b| /2$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b$ is non-zero

Tags: real-analysis

> If $|a-b |<| b |/ 2$, show $| a|> | b| /2$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b$ is non-zero.

Came across this in a proof of a theorem in Rudin's PMA which required this as a step, I understand this intuitively by drawing a line/circle but is there any algebraic way to show this?

Comment: The triangle inequality applied to the triangle $0ab$ at the complex plane should help. Note $|a-b|$ is the length of the line segment from $a$ to $b$ while $|b| = |b-0|$ is the distance between $0$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using Triangle Inequality,
$$|b|\leq |b-a|+|a|<\frac{|b|}{2}+|a|$$

Comment: Could you explain the right-most inequality?

Comment: @user376343 I have rephrased the problem statement. We are given that $a$ and $b$ satisfy.....

Comment: It is clear now.